# Difference between make_unique and make_unique with reference_wrapper in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

```
struct Foo{};
```

What is the difference between `std::make_unique<Foo>` and `std::make_unique<std::reference_wrapper<Foo>>`?

Answer (score 2):

`std::make_unique<Foo>`

returns

`std::unique_ptr<Foo>`.

---

`std::make_unique<std::reference_wrapper<Foo>>`

returns

`std::unique_ptr<std::reference_wrapper<Foo>>`.

---

`std::reference_wrapper` is a non-owning wrapper over a plain pointer. Which leads to `std::unique_ptr` owning `std::reference_wrapper<Foo>` which doesn't own `Foo` it refers to.

`std::unique_ptr<std::reference_wrapper<Foo>>` is equivalent to `std::unque_ptr<Foo*>`, where `Foo*` gets destroyed but `Foo` does not. It is easy to introduce memory leaks with it, defeating the purpose of `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: I know that it will return unique_ptr but I am more concerned about std::reference_wrapper here when it is combined with make_unique.

Answer (score 2):

`std::make_unique<Foo>` creates a `Foo` with dynamic storage duration, from whatever arguments are passed. `std::make_unique<Foo>(args...)` is a valid expression if and only if `Foo(args...)` is also valid.

`std::make_unique<std::reference_wrapper<Foo>>` creates a `std::reference_wrapper<Foo>` with dynamic storage duration, from either another `std::reference_wrapper<Foo>`, or from something that will bind to `Foo &` but not `Foo &&`. It does not create any additional `Foo`s, you need at least one `Foo` to exist somewhere already.

I can't think of a good reason to use `std::unique_ptr<std::reference_wrapper<Foo>>`, over either `gsl::observer<Foo>` (aka `Foo *`), `std::reference_wrapper<Foo>` or `std::unique_ptr<Foo>`, depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: you need at least one Foo to exist somewhere already -> If that's the case, the existing Foo should have been created by std::make_unique or not? And what happens to the existing Foo, once after std::make_unique<std::reference_wrapper<Foo>> is executed, then is it valid?

Comment: @sureshm somewhere there needs to be a `Foo` object for each reference to be bound to. It can have any storage duration. Binding a reference to an object does not change the object. There isn't any constraint on the `Foo` object being referred to, other than the usual caveats around avoiding dangling references.

Answer (score 1):

`std::make_unique<std::reference_wrapper<Foo>>` returns an owning smart pointer to a reference to `Foo`.

The reference-to-`Foo` is allocated on the heap.

No actual `Foo` is ever created.

For the same reason this won't compile:

```
auto x = std::make_unique<std::reference_wrapper<Foo>>();
```

Result:

```
error: 'std::reference_wrapper<Foo>': no appropriate default constructor available
```

The only way to make it work is to have it refer to some pre-existing `Foo`:

```
Foo foo;
auto x = std::make_unique<std::reference_wrapper<Foo>>(foo);
```

Can't think of a valid use-case for this.